# Excel chart (scatter plot) - X axis line behaves strangely

Tags: excel, charts

I've noticed this issue a couple of times over the past few years, even now that I've moved from Excel 2013 to Excel 2016 and have a different computer.

I produce a scatter plot, and set the axis line colors to black. Everything thing works as expected. Then I make a change to the underlying data, and the X axis line appears in the wrong place. As shown in the image below, the X axis line appears to be equal to around 4%, rather than 0% as you would expect. (To emphasize, the black lines are not data that is being plotted, but the result of formatting the axis lines to black).

[image]

If I close and re-open Excel file, or display it on a different screen, the issue resolves! The image below is exactly the same chart (and data) as shown above, but after I moved the open workbook from my primary monitor to my secondary monitor. Now the X axis line is where you would expect it to be!

[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue before, and any idea what causes it? I find it strange that it occurs on both new and older versions of Excel, different versions of Windows, and on different machines.

Thank you very much for your time,

Steve

Comment: When it is in the wrong position, does the X-axis stay there if you zoom in or out?

Comment: Good question: no it does not! It moves to where you would expect it.